# Как получить file_id медиа файла aiogram 2.x?

Tags: python-3.x, aiogram-2.x

Есть у меня следующий код который должен принимать file_id, но по какой-то причине он этого не делает...

```
@dp.message_handler(state=FSMAdmin_list.voice)
async def load_voice(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.from_user.id == admin:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['voice'] = message.voice.file_id
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        await FSMAdmin_list.next()
        await message.reply('Теперь введи текст который будет под голосовым')
```

А получить я пытаюсь этот file_id загружая файлы типа: m4a, ogg, mp3, просто голосовое, по фану решил док залить, но реакции 0...

Только на простое сообщение он наругался потому, что там нет атрибута file_id

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Внезапно на меня снизошло озарение и я решил эту ситуацию вспомнив об одной штуке под названием content_types, которую нужно засунуть в @dp.message_handler
таким образом -

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['audio'])
```

Тоже самое делается и для видео, фото, голосовых и т.д.

Мой рабочий кусок кода будет таким -

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['audio'],state=FSMAdmin_list.voice)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
async def load_voice(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.from_user.id == admin:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['voice'] = message.audio.file_id
        await FSMAdmin_list.next()
        await message.reply('Теперь введи текст который будет под голосовым')
```